# Banned for 1 year, is there any way to join sooner?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, account-suspension

I was banned for 1 year, this is my account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566863/ali-carikcioglu

Is there any way I can join sooner than 1 year? :)

I contacted Stack Overflow yesterday about this issue but didn't get any positive or negative response. Best would be if I could discuss this issue with a mod via email.

Comment: Most likely the stack exchange team is contacting the moderators in question, you will likely recieve a reply to your email soon

Comment: You contacted them 2 days ago according to your previous, now deleted, question. Just wait for a while. There is no need to post this here.

Comment: Wasn't the discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201859/1-year-ban-too-much) conclusive enough?

Comment: Then be patient.

Comment: You consistently show that you have *no patience*. Use that year to gain some. Moreover, your behaviour right now, deleting your downvoted question and reposting it, shows that you have not yet learned anything from the ban.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I believe the last one was deleted by a moderator

Comment: @alimcarikci Stop it. Move away from the computer. Wait for a response to your contact attempt, and let that be it. You are not going to do yourself any favours like this. Just be patient. They will eventually reply. That is your best bet.

Comment: @RichardTingle: the more reason to not repost the same thing again then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No argument there

Comment: Now the thing that's on everybody's mind: what got you suspended for a whole year? lol

Comment: @RichardTingle It was actually deleted by three 20k users, just for the record.

Comment: Also, @ali, you won't be e-mailing with a *moderator*, but with the Community Managers. They will contact any relevant moderator if need be.

Comment: @Michael: That is not necessarily any of our business.

Comment: Note that we're currently in New York for a summit, and taking a little longer than usual to reply to support email. Things will return to normal by the end of the week, and we should have everyone waiting for a reply taken care of by then.

Answer (score 20):

> I contacted stackoverflow yesterday about this issue but didn't get any positive or negative response. Best would be if I could discuss this issue with a mod via email.

Absolutely. Giving them one day is not nearly enough. Be patient and wait for the response. E-mail is indeed your best bet to settle this issue. Bringing this to the community won't do you any good.

So wait until you receive a reply. They might have more than a single issue to deal with.

Comment: @alimcarikci Just a note: This week, most SE employees will be very busy (there's a reason for that, but I'm not sure I can share it publicly). It will probably take a few more days (a week?) before they respond to your email, but they will respond eventually.

Comment: +1 for asking for patience.... *There goes a reversal* :)

Answer (score 13):

Looking over your history, I am not 100% sure why your account is suspended for a whole year. The last, direct suspension I see was for 7 days. I have a guess as to why the suspension is a year, but the staff will have to confirm that; I can't discuss that here without your consent, and it really is mostly a guess, so it's probably best to wait for the staff.

That said, it is certainly *possible* that your suspension could be lifted, especially if my guess is correct. I have a couple suggestions to 1) help that happen and 2) stay out of a suspension again.

1. Don't create any additional accounts. Absolutely not before your suspension is lifted, and I strongly encourage you to avoid doing so even after.
2. Work hard on being patient and understanding, and consider criticism as an attempt to honestly help you. Maybe certain criticism is 'wrong', but you'd do best to at least assume it is offered as an honest attempt to help.
3. Take the intervening time to read around a bit, and try to learn how to post better questions and answers.

I hope this works out well for you. We always want to try to be as forgiving as possible and give people an honest chance to improve, and get/give good help here. I am sure you are quite capable of being a quality contributor here, so I hope it works out.